# Is it okay to place a knob bore where it overlaps into the door rail?

Tags: doors

Is it okay to bore my knob hole when it overlaps into the lock rail? A standard 2 3/8" back set puts me outside of my stile. I'll have to find a non-standard latch or just bore out into the rail. Is there any problem with this, especially after I put in a dutchman to cover two old holes. 
[image: reference]

Comment: Have you checked the thickness of the door?  I'd be worried about that being non-standard as well.

Comment: I see no reason not to place the knob at the rail if it's at a usable height. My only concern would be the integrity of the door should you remove critical doweling or whatever with the bore.